# Highlighting Text and Making it Go to the Next Line in Itemize, and Removing Space at End of Highlighting, with Soul and Linegoal

Tags: lists, itemize, highlighting, soul, linegoal

I've been trying to split highlighted text into lines and not go over the margin in the `itemize` environment, but `linegoal` calculates the wrong margin in `itemize`. Also, the highlighting always gets to the end of the line, not the end of the text. Is it possible to make it go to the end of the text instead? Thank you!

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[top=4cm,bottom=4cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color, linegoal}

\begin{document}

\large
\colorbox{yellow}{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{This is pretty much fine, I guess, but this doesn't really work in itemize environment, also if possible get rid of the yellow space to the right of this text.}}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \colorbox{yellow}{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{This doesn't work, it is short by a little, and if possible, get rid of the yellow space to the right of this text as well.}}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to issue `\linegoal` before doing the `\parbox`.

Here I add `showframe` just to show the margins of the text block.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[top=4cm,bottom=4cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,asymmetric,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\highlightparbox}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \dimen@=\linegoal
  \dimen@=\dimexpr\dimen@-2\fboxsep+\@totalleftmargin\relax
  \colorbox{yellow}{\parbox[t]{\dimen@}{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\highlightparbox{This is pretty much fine, I guess, but this doesn't 
  really work in itemize environment, also if possible get 
  rid of the yellow space to the right of this text.}

\begin{itemize}
\item \highlightparbox{This doesn't work, it is short by a little, 
  and if possible, get rid of the yellow space to the right of 
  this text as well.}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]